# Save LINQ Query As Variable To Call Another LINQ Query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a var type storing the result of a LINQ query that I would like to use as a parameter for another LINQ query.

I am using for Controller:

```
  public async Task<ActionResult> Index(String aContainer)
    {
        var partsLocations = db.PartsLocations.Include(p => p.LocationType).Include(p => p.ManufacturingPlant);
        var empty = from y in db.PartsLocations select y;

                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(aContainer))
                    {              
                      var parentLoc = from a in db.PartsLocations
                                    where a.LocationName.Contains(aContainer)
                                    select a.ParentLocation;
                      var location = (from b in db.PartsLocations.Where(b => parentLoc.Equals(b.LocationID))
                                    select b).ToList();                             

                        return View( location.ToList());
                     }
        empty = empty.Where(r => r.LocationName.Contains(null));
        return View(await empty.ToListAsync());
    }
```

My View is:

```
@model IEnumerable<Parts.PartsLocation>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
 }
```

Model:

```
 public int LocationID { get; set; }
    public int TypeID { get; set; }
    public string LocationName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int PlantID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> BayID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> SecurityGroupID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ParentLocation { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> LastMoved { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
```

But I am getting error: "Unable to cast the type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types."

In SQL I do something like:

SELECT ParentLocation FROM PartsLocations where LocationName = 'aContainer';

SELECT * FROM PartsLocations where LocationID = ParentLocation;

How can I use the result of a LINQ query as a parameter for a separate query? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This

```
              var parentLoc = from a in db.PartsLocations
                            where a.LocationName.Contains(aContainer)
                            select a.ParentLocation;
```

is not a result.  It is a query.

If you want a result, run the query:

```
var location = parentLoc.Single();
```

Try, something like:

```
              var parentLoc = (from a in db.PartsLocations
                               where a.LocationName == aContainer
                               select a.ParentLocation).Single();

              var locations = (from b in db.PartsLocations
                               where b.LocationID == parentLoc
                               select b).ToList();
```

Comment: I replaced the second query with 'var location = parentLoc.Single();' as you suggested but now I get error: 'The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Int32', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Parts.PartsLocation]'.

Comment: @ David Browne- I am actually needing a record set returned for my second LINQ query, with parentLoc as a parameter.

Comment: Still, using navigation properties is much more succinct and it takes only one database roundtrip.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you are looking for locations having `parentloc` as parent locations. You can easily do that by using a navigation property `PartsLocation.ParentLocation` that refers to the parent location. You should be able to add that property and rename the current `ParentLocation` property to `ParentLocationId`:

```
var location = (from b in db.PartsLocations
                where b.ParentLocation.LocationName.Contains(aContainer)
                select b).ToList();
```