# LINQ Query Variable passed to Another LINQ Query

Tags: linq

What is the difference between the query in this post:
[Save LINQ Query As Variable To Call Another LINQ Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834576/save-linq-query-as-variable-to-call-another-linq-query)

```
var parentLoc = (from a in db.PartsLocations
                where a.LocationName == aContainer
                select a.ParentLocation);

var locations = (from b in db.PartsLocations
                where b.LocationID == parentLoc
                select b).ToList();
```

to the following example from [this](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/blogs/tool-tracker/2015/12/combine-linq-queries.aspx) post.

```
Dim persVogel = From p In db.People
                Where p.LastName = "Vogel"
                Select p

Dim persVogelPHVIS = From pp In persVogel
                     Where pp.Company.Name = "PHVIS"
                     Select pp
```

Both of these have declared 2 queries and use the first query variable into second query.
What is the reason to use Single() in the first example but was not used in visualstudiomagazine.com article? Thanks

Comment: `Single()`? Where? Doesn't the usage of both results make it evident?

Comment: your first example is C#, second is VB, which is confusing

Comment: Thanks Brett. Could one then infer that the database is queried twice in first example - One to get Single() and then while processing second query?

Comment: I believe that's true, yes.  The query would be executed when we start to iterate over the results, which would need to happen when we assign the result of the `Single()` method call to the variable `parentLoc`, and then when we call `ToList()` at the end of the second statement.  Strictly speaking, the second sample never calls the database ... but one assumes there would be some sort of operation on the results after these two statements :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two samples are fundamentally different.

**First Sample**

I think you pasted this one incorrectly...from the referenced question, the query should be:

```
var parentLoc = (from a in db.PartsLocations
                 where a.LocationName == aContainer
                 select a.ParentLocation).Single();

var locations = (from b in db.PartsLocations
                 where b.LocationID == parentLoc
                 select b).ToList();
```

(I am going to assume that `LocationID` and `ParentLocation` are typed as `int`.)

In this sample `parentLoc` is an `int` - a single instance of a `ParentLocation` value, obtained from the `PartsLocations` table.  So what you get is an `int`.

The second linq statement sources its records also from the `PartsLocations` table.  It uses `parentLoc` to identify records within that table (e.g. `where b.LocationID == parentLoc`).  What you get at the end is a set of `PartsLocations` records.

The `.Single()` call is made because you want to compare the result to `LocationID` in the second statement, and cannot compare `int` to `IEnumerable<int>`.

**Second Sample**

```
Dim persVogel = From p In db.People
                Where p.LastName = "Vogel"
                Select p

Dim persVogelPHVIS = From pp In persVogel
                     Where pp.Company.Name = "PHVIS"
                     Select pp
```

In the second sample, `persVogel` is a subset of records from the `People` table (specifically, the subset of people with `LastName == "Vogel"`) - so what you get is a set of `People` records.

The second linq statement is based on this subset of records (`From pp In persVogel`) and further filters them down to records where `pp.Company.Name = "PHVIS"`.  What you get is still a set of `People` records.

These two statements could easily be compressed into one single statement:

```
Dim persVogelPHVIS = From p In db.People
                     Where p.LastName = "Vogel"
                     AndAlso p.Company.Name = "PHVIS"
                     Select p
```

You will still get a set of `People` records at the end.